# Cannot serve directory no matching directory Zend Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I'm trying to display a list of all the videos in one directory under the public folder in a Zend Framework app. However, when I try and load them, I am running into an error of

```
[Fri Feb 16 14:25:24.903182 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 6572:tid 2008] [client ::1:59747] AH01276: Cannot serve directory C:/xampp/htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/videos/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://localhost/members
```

Now, no errors occur when I load and display lists of images from the same directory but it does this for the videos directory.

Here is my php code in the controller:

```
$video_dir = @array_diff(scandir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $params . '/videos/', 1), array('.', '..', 'current', '.htaccess', 'albums', 'edited_photos'));

if (count($video_dir) > 0) {
    $videos = array();

    foreach ($video_dir as $video) {
       $videos[] = "<video width=\"200\" height=\"150\">
           <source src=\"$video\" type=\"video/mp4\">
           </video>";
    }

    natsort($videos);

    $layout->setVariable('my_videos', $videos);
}
```

the view:

```
<div id="side-5" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <div class="w3-row-padding" id="left-videos">
        <?php
            if (count($this->layout()->my_videos) > 0):
                foreach ($this->layout()->my_videos as $vids):
        ?>

            <div class="w3-half">
                <?php echo $vids; ?>
            </div>

            <?php
                 endforeach;
            else:
            ?>
               <p>Upload <a href="<?php echo $this->url('members/profile', array('action' => 'upload-file')); ?>">videos</a>!</p> 
            <?php

            endif;
            ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought it might be a htaccess file related issue, so here is the htaccess file I have in place:

```
 Options -Indexes
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?localhost [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

and just in case it helps, here is a screenshot of the directory:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

(Sorry if this could be a duplicate question, I just couldn't find anything with Zend Framework 2)

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it was a path error, sorry.